# invalid date error for %m%d%Y format

Tags: shell-script, date

I want to convert a String in %m%d%Y format to date.

But, getting invalid date error as shown below:

```
bash-4.1$ date -d '10042015' +"%m%d%Y"
date: invalid date `10042015'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Should be `20151004` or `10/04/2015`

Comment: Does it mean, in shell script only these 2 formats are supported? It seems strange to me. In this case, how shall I convert 10042015 string into date?

Comment: or read `man bash` and look for Substring Expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `date` `+` option sets only the *output* format, not the input. You'll need to use a different tool or format the string first:

```
date --date="$(sed 's/^\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)$/\3-\1-\2/' <<< '10042015')"
```

or

```
date --date="$(sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)/\3-\1-\2/' <<< '10042015')"
```

or simply

```
date --date="$(sed 's/\(.*\)\(....\)$/\2\1/' <<< '10042015')"
```

(thanks [@Costas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236363/invalid-date-error-for-mdy-format/236375#comment404502_236375)). Even though the last two are shorter I would still suggest the first one, because:

1. it's stricter, avoiding strange bugs if handling strings from third party tools or users, and, more importantly,
2. it's more maintainable, since it's more obvious what the code is doing (rearranging three numbers and putting hyphens between them as opposed to moving the last four characters to the start of the string).

Comment: The OP use `%m%d%Y` format so `sed 's/\(.*\)\(....$\)/\2\1/'` is enough